# SFTP/FTP connection timeouts when left unused for few minutes

Tags: linux, ftp, sftp

I am running **Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa** (Xfce 4.14.2) and I have this issue where I am programming something using SFTP/FTP connection through Thunar, and if I stay too long without editing/modifying/saving any files through SFTP connection, it will disconnect me, meaning I need to unmount the "directory" and then connect again.

The way I have connected to my SFTP/FTP is that I simply just go from my Thunar to `Go->Open Location` and write my SFTP/FTP connection string there `sftp://ip-here/`. I have it saved(/mounted?) currently, so I don't need to write it anymore, making it easier for me to just double-click the directory to open it.

I have tried to tweak my SSH config increasing the `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax` to 1 hour, but this seems to have no effect.

How can I increase the timeout time, so it would not disconnect me from the server too often?

**Server's SSH settings**

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
```

**My computer's SSH settings**

```
Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    ServerAliveInterval 300
    ServerAliveCountMax 3
```

Comment: [Decrease the interval](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446441/108618).

Comment: This might be a parameter on the server, rather than the client. Which software is used on the server? Are you in control of it?

Comment: Plesk and yes @harrymc the other server that I regularly use that has the same connection timeout issue is just Debian based home server

Comment: Please add to your post the SSH config files for both client and server.

Comment: Yes, sorry, just edited my question with the config files you asked for @harrymc

Comment: Did decreasing the interval help? Another thing: note SSH config is relevant for SFTP, while FTP has no connection to SSH whatsoever. You keep writing "SFTP/FTP", but I'm not sure if FTP is ever involved. Is it?

Comment: Try in `sshd_config` to add `ClientAliveInterval  1200` and `ClientAliveCountMax 3`. The Timeout value will be "1200 seconds * 3 = 3600" seconds, so the ssh session will remain alive for idle time of 1 hour without dropping.

Comment: Well, I explained how I connect to the machine with my Linux, I connect through Tunar writing `sftp://ip-here/`, I read somewhere that SSH config has something to do with the connection... @KamilMaciorowski

Comment: Are you using ssh key authentication?  Thonar might retry if your keys are setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be hitting a NAT timeout or something strange.  Others noted the use of ClientAliveInterval and ClientAliveCountMax in the comments.  This is what my config has been using for years:

```
ServerAliveInterval 45
ServerAliveCountMax 60
```

On the server side you could try this:

```
ClientAliveInterval 60
TCPKeepAlive yes
```

Also see this in another SE community:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200239/how-can-i-keep-my-ssh-sessions-from-freezing

Answer (score 0):

If it is a problem with Thonar, then try the SSHFS FUSE filesystem:

- `sudo apt-get install sshfs`
- `sshfs-mount -o reconnect user@remotehost:/some/dir/ /home/me/mountpoint/`

If you use SSH keys for authentication then `-o reconnect` will work great.  If not, leave off `-o reconnect`.

Note that once sshfs has mounted you can use it like a normal filesystem, so no need to use sftp:// locations.